# Spring-based web application fails at startup on WAS Liberty

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty

I'm writing a simple Spring-based web application and deploy it to Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.9.   The deployment fails because the application start fails.  The message in `console.log` is

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application userSetting.
           The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.metadata.MetaDataException:
           com.ibm.wsspi.adaptable.module.UnableToAdaptException:
           com.ibm.ws.javaee.ddmodel.DDParser$ParseException: CWWKC2262E: The server is
           unable to process the 3.1 version and the http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee namespace
           in the /META-INF/web-fragment.xml deployment descriptor on line 23.
```

The last part of the message makes now sense since I don't hav `/META-INF` or `/WEB-INF` in the Eclipse project for the application, since I'm deploying with Gradle:  `gradle clean build deploy`.

I've tried all kinds of modifications to the project and, in desperation, I've cut it down to only have the following source code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserSettingApplication {

  private static final LoggerUtils logger = new LoggerUtils( UserSettingApplication.class );

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.debug( "Entering UserSettingApplication.main()" );
    SpringApplication.run(UserSettingApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Can you please advise me how to fix this service start-up problem?

server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <featureManager>
      <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

   <!-- Define the host name for use by the collective.
        If the host name needs to be changed, the server should be
        removed from the collective and re-joined. -->
   <variable name="defaultHostName" value="localhost" />

    <!-- Define an Administrator and non-Administrator -->
   <basicRegistry id="basic">
      <user name="admin" password="********" />
      <user name="nonadmin" password="***********" />
   </basicRegistry>

   <!-- Assign 'admin' to Administrator -->
   <administrator-role>
      <user>admin</user>
   </administrator-role>

   <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="*******" />

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

        <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
        <applicationManager autoExpand="false"/>
</server>
```

Comment: can you update your question with your server.xml?  I suspect you do not have the `servlet-3.1` feature enabled

Comment: Added server.xml; and/but, I *was* able to use this same server to successfully deploy another Spring-based web application.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears to be caused by some of your build tooling generating a web-fragment.xml with a Servlet 3.1 schema.

Currently, you have the `jsp-2.2` feature enabled, which by default enables `servlet-3.0`.

To fix the problem, I would recommend upgrading from `jsp-2.2` to `jsp-2.3` (which will pull in servlet-3.1), or adding `<feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>` to just enable all of the Java EE 7 web profile features (servlet, JPA, bean validation, cdi, jsf, etc).

So your new server.xml could look like this:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
      <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
      <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

<!-- rest of file unchanged.... -->
```

Comment: Andy, before trying your suggestion, I recopied my `build.gradle` from the project that was working successfully, and now my project is starting up successfully, too.   I'm not sure what specific change enabled this, but I'll take it...